# PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error..)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, video, android-video-player

I have this method

```
Future<void> uploadVideo(BuildContext context) async {
  File videoFile = widget.videoFile;
  print("videoFile $videoFile"); //this gives: File: '/data/user/0/com.---/app_flutter/tutorVideo/1610097782457.mp4'
  setState(() {
    isLoading = true;
  });

  StorageReference fileStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('tutorDetails')
      .child(AuthModel().currentUser.uid)
      .child('Video')
      .child(basename(videoFile.path));

  print("storage ${fileStorageReference.path}"); //this gives: storage tutorDetails/Kb2BmJnNWnMjxartXoXcmZGRjxg2/Video/1610097782457.mp4

  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = fileStorageReference.putFile(videoFile);

  StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;

  String downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

  UserModel().updateProfileFields({
    'videoUrl': downloadUrl,
    "tutorApplicationVideoFlag": true,
  });

  setState(() {
    isLoading = false;
  });

  Navigator.popUntil(
      context, ModalRoute.withName(TutorApplicationScreen.path));
}
```

and I am using the latest version of video_player flutter plugin {I updated it}, but i am having these errors

> Playback error

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)

> Unhandled Exception: 'package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 62 pos 12: 'file.existsSync()': is not true.

**Note: It works on some devices normally and withoud any error, but on others no. Any thoughts? Thanks**

Comment: On what android versions and what type of devices it does not work?

Comment: @Nuts I am using huawei y6 2

Answer (score -1):

The issue was solved by updating the code, checking the docs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you solved it? Thanks

Comment: @jennie788 The code written above was old written, so my teammate update it to the newest since it solved the old issues. You can check it here https://pub.dev/packages/video_player